# Python -- function to read file and sort info

Tags: python, sorting, file-read

Restaurant sorting. The text file scores.txt contains a series of local restaurant ratings. Each line looks like this:

Restaurant Name: Rating

I'm trying to write a program that reads the file and then spits out the ratings In alphabetical order by restaurant.

These are the contents of the scores.rtf file:

```
Pancho Villa:3
Andalu:3
Urbun Burger:1
El Toro:5
Casa Thai:2
Taqueria Cancun:2
Little Baobab:1
Charanga:3
Irma's Pampanga:5
Bay Blend Coffee and Tea:3
Giordano Bros:2
Two Amy's: 5
Chef Geoff: 3
```

I'm not sure where to start with this.

Comment: `Your job is to write a program` <- what's the salary?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget nah sounds more like a homework assignment. He mentions at the bottom "I'm not sure where to start with this" so I'm taking him at his word.

Comment: @AdamSmith: I was sure of it, but couldn't find the handout...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this isn't a code-writing service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's think through this. You have an input with a regular format: a name and a value, separated by a colon `:`. You'll need to **open** the file and **read** each line, then **split** the line into two parts, name and value. Think about what kind of data structure would be best for holding these values. Once you've read through the file and closed it, you just need to **sort** your data structure alphabetically, and **print** out the contents. Easy enough?

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator
with open('scores.txt') as infile:
    for stuff in sorted([line.strip().split(":") for line in infile], key=lambda iGotThisFromStackOverflow: [operator.itemgetter(0)(iGotThisFromStackOverflow)][0]):
        print(stuff)
```

Comment: I prefer to toss in stuff he couldn't possibly know about, or unnecessary arcane imports (`from hashlib import sha256` or etc)

Comment: @AdamSmith: did you miss the `lambda` in the `sort`? Edited out to use operator now :P

Comment: No, that was what I was preferring the arcane imports to! :) Ooh `operator.itemgetter` is a good one. You would score extra points if it was `key=lambda x: [operator.itemgetter(0)(x)][0]` :)

Comment: @AdamSmith: done! Quite conniving eh!

Comment: MORE OBFUSCATION! `line.strip().split(chr(0b111010))` :D

Comment: @AdamSmith oh that is too good! How about `chr(int('111010', 0b10))`?

Comment: Oh if you're going to do that, put it in some funky base! (we're having entirely too much fun with this........)

Comment: @AdamSmith: `chr(int('10', int('111010', 0b10)))`?

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.